# jQuery using store selector to find child elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I often use the `this` keyword within a `foreach` loop to select a child element of `this`

```
$('.width', this).val();
```

But can I do the same with a stored variable?  Something like:

```
var window = $('#window');
$('.width', window).val();
```

I would like to store `$('#window')` as it's used often in my code.  I thought I could use the above method, but it is not working for me.

**UPDATE**
The element in question that I'm looking for is:

```
<div id="window">
    <input class="width" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax

```
$(child, inContext)
```

is the same as

```
$(inContext).find(child)
```

so yes, you can do

```
var window = $('#window');
window.find('width').val();
```

And note that `width` looks for an element like `<width value="xxx"></width>`, which seems strange

Comment: thanks.  To clarify  I updated my question to explain the element I'm looking for is `<input class="width" type="text" />`

Comment: Should I be able to use `$('.width', window).val();` or is my only option `window.find('width').val();`

Comment: Both should work fine, as long as the element is **inside** the `#window` element. And don't name your variable `window`, that name is already taken.

Comment: @andeneo thanks, I was just using the var name `window` in my example.  Got it working both ways.  This is good practice for performance right? Or is it overkill?  I'm using the `$('#window')` 6 times so I thought this way would be better

Comment: If you're using the same element many times, keeping it in a variable so it doesn't have to be looked every time is indeed good practice.